# C program only outputs 0

Tags: c

my C program only outputs 0.000 and i have no idea why

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(){
    int count;
    double input; 
    double output = DBL_MAX;
    int i;  

  printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
  scanf("%i", &count);
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%f", &input);

    if(output>input)
    {
        (output = input);
    }

  }
   printf("The smallest number is: %f", output);
}
```

the code compiles fine but just seems to no either not scan it properly or some other issue i'm just not seeing.

Comment: `%f` is for `float`, use `%lf` to input a `double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `%f` to `%lf` (in `printf` and `scanf`), since output and input are declared as `double`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(){
int count;
double input; 
double output = DBL_MAX;
int i;  

printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
scanf("%i", &count);
for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
printf("Enter a number:");
scanf("%lf", &input);

if(output>input)
{
    (output = input);
}

}
 printf("The smallest number is: %lf", output);
}
```

Idoene link: http://ideone.com/BspQwf

Answer (score 2):

The correct specifier for a type `double` is `%lf`.

You pass the address of a double variable to scanf() and tell it it is an address of a float `%f`.

The function then overflows and you get an incorrect result.